# Adding UIButton to detailTextLabel/right side of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm quite new to Swift and I would like to know what is the easiest and simplest way for me to add in 10 buttons to 10 of my cell rows in my TableViewController.

P.S: It would be nice if the 10 buttons perform differently instead of duplicate.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()
class TableViewController5: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference
        // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts3").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            postData.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key

                postData.append(key)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return postData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 23)
        cell.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
            return 80
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What will the buttons do? Why buttons? Why not just allow the user to tap on a row?

Comment: didSelect Method - will get which row tapped. then in that method you can proceed appropriate view controller

Comment: Sorry forgot to explain further because this is a voting app. The user needs to tap on the vote button along the 10 booths then it will segue to another page

Comment: but the page will be same for every user right?

Comment: yea probably same page but different labels and contents.

Comment: You don't need a button. You can do the segue when the user taps on the row.

Comment: @rmaddy It could be a client requirement.

Comment: yea my boss wants a button instead :/

Comment: One cell One button or one cell 10 button ?

Comment: one cell one button :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you should use prototype cell and add an IBAction in the cell and in that cell you should perform the segue and pass whatever data you need to customise the page you load.

In your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, you can set a tag for the button.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? prototypeCell

    cell.voteButton.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

Then in your cell's class, in the IBAction I mentioned earlier, check for the tag and set the data to pass accordingly.

Then in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, just pass the data you want to pass to the next view controller and all should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it helps You

```
//Common cell Variable 
var cell = UITableViewCell()

//UIButton commonly Declared
var acceptRequest = UIButton()
var declineRequest = UIButton()
```

My TableView Cell contains two button as shown **Accept & Decline**

[image]

In my **tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)** I added Handlers for button

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Cell for dequeuing 
        cell = self.RequestListTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        //Used Tags here
        //You can Make use of TableViewCell class here and Access Buttons from there
        acceptRequest = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton

        //Adding action Handlers for UIbuttons
        self.acceptRequest.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RequestListView.AcceptRequest(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
}
```

**my Button handler**

```
func AcceptRequest (sender: UIButton) {
    //Dequeue cell with identifier can be ignored 
    cell = self.RequestListTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!

    //Get button position from TableView : Required
    let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.RequestListTableView)

    //Get index Path of selected Cell from TableView 
    //Returns Table Cell index same as didSelect 
    let indexPath : IndexPath = self.RequestListTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!

    //Can be used if you need to update a view 
    cell = self.RequestListTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

   //Now time to access using index Path 
     cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row] //Example

}
```

**Can use this Procedure for even single Button or for multiple buttons too**

**In case if you have more than one button in one cell, this will help you**